# How can I resize image with quality without saving image in Python?

Tags: image-resizing

I use this code but it need to save

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
image = img.resize((W, H), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image.save('De7k.jpeg', optimize=True, quality=Quality)
```

Comment: If you don't want to save the image, what do you need to do with it?

Comment: I want to return it as base64 encoding ( Api take url image and return resized image as json file with base64 encoding )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to "save" the file while keeping it in memory instead of writing a file to disk, you can write it to another BytesIO object.

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
image = img.resize((W, H), Image.ANTIALIAS)
output = BytesIO()
image.save(output, format="JPEG", optimize=True, quality=Quality)
```